# Basic C++ program crashes VS 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I'm following [this tutorial](http://geeklit.blogspot.com/2006/08/calling-c-lib-from-c.html) on wrapping a .lib in a C++ DLL.

Right after I use the VS wizard to generate a Win32 DLL project, everything compiles just fine.

Then, following the tutorial, I substitute this VS-generated code:

```
DEMODLL_API int fnDemoDll(void)
{
    return 42;
}
```

for this code:

```
DEMODLL_API int fnDemoDll(int a,int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

When I then build, the VS 2008 SP1 IDE crashes.

Google turned up several hits for this type of crash, but nothing that seems to apply.

There is an entry in the event viewer related to the crash:

> Faulting application devenv.exe,
>   version 9.0.30729.1, time stamp
>   0x488f2b50, faulting module
>   VCProjectEngine.dll, version
>   9.0.30729.1, time stamp 0x488f2e94, exception code 0xc0000005, fault
>   offset 0x0003dd11, process id 0x1f80,
>   application start time
>   0x01ca98d27f9c8b85.

UPDATE:

I recreated the project, compiled it was fine, changed

```
return 42;
```

to

```
return 43;
```

and VS crashed again.

Comment: I would to do it without code generation and write it manually myself.

Comment: I would think that the project wizard has been used a bijillion times and doubt it's a problem with the actual code.

Comment: It's not that the wizard code is incorrect, just that by writing it all yourself you are more aware of all aspects of the code, which may help you find the bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact code is probably irrelevant. It's the IDE, not the compiler that crashes. Can you start the build in another way?

Comment: I'll look into building from the command line when I get home tonight (this is a hobby project).

Comment: I found a way to avoid using C++ in my project so never resolved this.  DevEnv also crashes when compiling from the command line.  I may dust this off when VS2010 is RTM.  Accepting because the answer is accurate and does provide a way forward.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems with my VS 2008. To me what was happening was that the IDE suddenly closed with no more info.

I then tried to debug the IDE with [DebugDiag](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=28BD5941-C458-46F1-B24D-F60151D875A3). This program can debug external applications, dump their symbols, do a stack trace, etc. It can be very helpful for these kinds of problems, where you have no idea what could be causing such a problem.

My problem was solved by disabling the Intellisense by renaming it to a new name (so then it was disabled). Your problem can be different, but [DebugDiag](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=28BD5941-C458-46F1-B24D-F60151D875A3) can help you diagnose that.

If you wan to try disabling Intellisense and see if it works for you, try renaming *\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcpackages\feacp.dll* to something else and see if it works. However, this doesn't seem to be your problem.

Comment: I agree that it's probably not Intellisense since the crash happens during build, but I'll give it a try anyhow.  Thanks for sharing your experience.